# Until + present perfect, simple past

Tags: tense

I came across this sentence in a book:

> Until the machinery has been installed, the plant wasn't able to begin production.

Is this grammatically correct?

I think the first clause should use either the simple past or the past perfect, because it talks about something in the past:

> Until the machinery **had been installed** / **was installed**, the plant wasn't able to begin production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all correct alternatives to your original sentence

> Until the machinery ***was*** installed, the plant wasn't able to begin production.
>   Until the machinery ***had been*** installed, the plant wasn't able to begin production.
>
> Until the machinery has been installed, the plant ***won't be*** able to begin production.
>
> Until the machinery ***is*** installed, the plant ***will not be*** able to begin production.